# Функция str_replace() работает некорректно

Tags: php, translit

```
function translitlot_kir($value){
    $converter = array(
'o‘'=>'ў','O‘'=>'Ў',' E'=>' Э','E'=>' Э','Ya'=>'Я','Yu'=>'Ю','Yo'=>'Ё','yo'=>'ё','G‘'=>'Ғ','Ch'=>'Ч','Sh'=>'Ш','ʼ'=>'ъ',' e'=>' э','ya'=>'я','yu'=>'ю','ye'=>'е','’'=>'ъ','g‘'=>'ғ','ch'=>'ч','sh'=>'ш','A'=>'А','B'=>'Б','C'=>'С','D'=>'Д','F'=>'Ф','G'=>'Г','H'=>'Ҳ','I'=>'И','J'=>'Ж','K'=>'К','L'=>'Л','M'=>'М','N'=>'Н','O' => 'О','P'=>'П','Q'=>'Қ','R'=>'Р','S'=>'С','T'=>'Т','U'=>'У','V'=>'В','W'=>'В','X'=>'Х','Y'=>'Й','Z'=>'З',

'a'=>'а','b'=>'б','c'=>'с','d'=>'д','e'=>'е','f'=>'ф','g'=>'г','h'=>'ҳ','i'=>'и','j'=>'ж','k'=>'к','l'=>'л','m'=>'м','n'=>'н','o'=>'о','p'=>'п','q'=>
'қ','r'=>'р','s'=>'с','t'=>'т','u'=>'у','v'=>'в','w'=>'в','x'=>'х','y'=>'й','z'=>'з',
'[br]' => '<br>',
'<p>' => '<p>','</p>' => '</p>',
'<i>' => '<i>','</i>' => '</i>',
'<u>' => '<u>','</u>' => '</u>',
'<ul>' => '<ul>','</ul>' => '</ul>',
'<li>' => '<li>','</li>' => '</li>',
'<em>' => '<em>','</em>' => '</em>',
'<strong>' => '<strong>','</strong>' => '</strong>',
'<code>' => '<code>','</code>' => '</code>',
    );

    $value = str_replace(array_keys($converter),array_values($converter),$value);
    return $value;
}
```

В этот код работает частично, буквы меняются, но коды не меняются.

Например: `'[br]' => '<br>'`. Это не изменилось, и эти тоже `'<p>' => '<p>','</p>' => '</p>'`.

Вот еще пример с сайта: текст `"Quyidagi ishlar tahoratda makruhi tanzihiy hisoblanadi:[br]"` изменило на `"Қуйидаги ишлар таҳоратда макруҳи танзиҳий ҳисобланади:[бр]"`. А если вместо "`[br]`" я пишу "`<br>`", резултат будет "`<бр>`"

Подскажите, в чем проблема?

Comment: Проблема в том, что вы неверно ей пользуетесь и $value не определено при передаче в функцию. https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.str-replace.php

Comment: @becouse с чего вы взяли что оно не определено? тем более, что автор, пишет, что частично все заменилось?

Comment: зы: автор, вам не кажется, что должно быть `'[p]' => '<p>'` а не то, что у вас?

Comment: Вот еще пример с сайта: текст "Quyidagi ishlar tahoratda makruhi tanzihiy hisoblanadi:[br]" изменило на "Қуйидаги ишлар таҳоратда макруҳи танзиҳий ҳисобланади:[бр]". А если вместо "[br]" я пишу "<br>", резултат будет "<бр>".

Answer (score 1):

Вот что происходит. Есть замены

```
'b'=>'б',
'r'=>'р',
'[br]' => '<br>',
```

Функция делает замены по порядку, поэтому получается [br] => [бр] : сработали первые две замены, а до третьей замены дело не дошло.

Надо разделить замены для тегов типа '[br]' => '
', и для текста 'b'=>'б'. Сначала делать замены для тегов, а потом сделать замены для текста, не трогая теги.

Первое делается обычным str_replace, а вот второе сделать сложнее. Например, можно "откусывать" по одному символу из строки и считать сколько было "<" и ">". Если кол-во "<" и ">" одинаково, то мы в тексте и можно производить замену данного символа, иначе символ переносим как есть, без изменений.

Comment: Дополню: "некоррекстное поведение" - очень даже хорошо задокументировано [описание функции str_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.str-replace.php#refsect1-function.str-replace-notes)

Comment: не работает ребята... Пожалуйста. помогите...

Comment: Давайте по шагам, тут как минимум два шага. Где именно, и как не работает?

Comment: для примера я ввод этот: 
     `echo translit("<h2>Privet</h2><br><p>Kak delo</p>");`
я получу это:
    `<ҳ2>Привет<бр><п>Как дело`

Comment: похоже вы так и не прочитали, что я написал. Если прочитали - то сделали? Работает замена тегов отдельно? Работает замена текста вне тегов?

Comment: да, вы имели в виду как это:?
`"<"=>"<",
">"=>">",
"<strong>"=>"<strong>",
"</strong>"=>"</strong>",`

Comment: извини мой русски не хорошо, и я не профессионал в php